# How can we create a load balancer for public IPs?

Tags: networking, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

In our current setup, we have 2 datacenters with the same application. We want to have a cloud load balancer, to detect the best destination for requests.

Is it possible to create a load balancer in GCP, without configuring any VMs in GCP? How can we setup a load balancer for public IPs?

Comment: What criteria will be used to determine 'best destination'?

Answer (score 0):

You can use External HTTP(S) Load Balancing with Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP) wich is supported with the following backend types:

- Instance groups
- Zonal network endpoint groups (NEGs)
- Serverless NEGs: One or more Cloud Run services
- Internet NEGs, for endpoints that are outside of Google Cloud (also known as custom origins).

https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/load-balancer-howto#enable-iap

An Internet Network Endpoint Group (NEG) defines an external backend for a load balancer. An external backend is a backend that resides outside of Google Cloud. You can use this type of backend with a Google Cloud external HTTP(S) load balancer. You should do this when you want to serve content from an external backend, and you want your external HTTP(S) load balancer to be the frontend.

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/internet-neg-concepts